# Using Applicative notation for parsers whose result is discarded

Tags: haskell, refactoring, parsec, applicative

I have a question on refactoring [Parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) code to use the `Applicative` interface. Suppose I have a parser using the monadic interface like this:

```
filePath0 :: GenParser Char st Info
filePath0 = do
  optional (string "./")
  r <- artist
  slash
  l <- album
  slash
  t <- track
  return $ Song r l t
```

I'd like to turn it into something like this:

```
filePath :: GenParser Char st Info
filePath = Song <$> artist <*> album <*> track
```

But as you can see it is not complete. My question: where, in this refactored version, would I insert `optional (string "./")` and `slash` parsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `*>` and `<*` to include actions whose result is discarded (but their effect is run):

```
(*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
(<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
```

giving

```
filePath :: GenParser Char st Info
filePath = optional "./" *> Song <$> artist <*> slash *> album <*> slash *> track
```

Comment: You can also use `<$ :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a` to keep "the semantics" at the far left.